# Loading screen upon doInBackground(String... params) and geocoder issues

Tags: java, android, android-gps

I am trying to obtain location (Lat, Long, Address) via GPS/Cellular in my android application. This is the code below :

```
private class LocAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Obtaining location...Please Wait...");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            LocationDSR locationDSR=new LocationDSR(getActivity());
            locationDSR.getListAddressFromGeocoder();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println("Location obtained");
            dialog.hide();
        }

    }
```

And here is the locationDSR java :

```
public class LocationDSR implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    Context c;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location currentLocation;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public LocationDSR(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        ApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    synchronized void ApiClient() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(c)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLocation = location;
        System.out.println("onLocation changed :"+currentLocation);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setInterval(10 * 1000) // every 10 minutes
                    .setExpirationDuration(10 * 1000) // After 10 seconds
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    public void getListAddressFromGeocoder() {
        new AddressAsync().execute();
        System.out.println("Inside getListAddressFromGeocoder");

    }

    class AddressAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference(c);

            System.out.println("Inside doInBackground");

            System.out.println("Current location : " + currentLocation);
            if (currentLocation == null) {
                LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) c.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                System.out.println("Current location null block");
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    }
                    currentLocation = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    System.out.println("Obtraining from GPS");
                    System.out.println("GPSlocation : "+currentLocation);
                    // Check both providers even for lastKnownLocation
                    if (currentLocation == null) {
                        currentLocation = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        System.out.println("Obtaining from network provider");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Insiode catch block for current location not obtained");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (currentLocation != null) {
                String complete_address;
                final double latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();

                System.out.println("LATITUDE: " + currentLocation.getLatitude());
                System.out.println("LONGITUDE: " + currentLocation.getLongitude());

                sharedPreference.saveLatLogAddressPref(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(latitude), "Not available", true);

                //Storing the latitude and longitude in sharedPreference (To be used in case address is not obtained or geocoder timesout)

                ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(c);

                if (cd.isInternetOn()) {
                    System.out.println("Internet on detected");

                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(c);
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Latitude for address : "+latitude);
                            System.out.println("Longitude for address : "+longitude);
                            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);

                            Address addr = null;
                            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                                addr = addresses.get(0);
                                String info = "Address is:  ";
                                info += addr.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? addr
                                        .getAddressLine(0) : "";
                                info = info + ", " + addr.getLocality() + ", "
                                        + addr.getCountryName();
                                System.out.println("INFO : "+info);
                            } else
                                System.out.println("Address not found");



                            if (addresses != null || addresses.size() > 0) {
                                System.out.println("Addresses : "+addresses);

                                for (Address address : addresses) {
                                    complete_address = String.valueOf(address.getAddressLine(0) + " " + address.getAddressLine(1) + " " + address.getAddressLine(2));
                                    System.out.println("Complete address : "+complete_address);
                                    if (complete_address.equals(" null null"))
                                    {
                                        complete_address = String.valueOf(address.getAdminArea()+" "+address.getLocality());
                                        sharedPreference.saveLatLogAddressPref(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(latitude), complete_address, true);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sharedPreference.saveLatLogAddressPref(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(latitude), complete_address, true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("Inside catch for geocoder");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

    }


}
```

The loading screen however pops up showing " Obtaining location...Please Wait..." but only for like 2 seconds. Within that time only the Latitude and Longitudes are obtained and not the Address. It takes about 2-3 seconds more for the address query  `addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);` to get completed (as I can see it in the logcat). I am unable to understand how to keep the loading screen for the address query as well.

Also, sometimes during querying the address via gecoder, it shows

> java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your second `AsyncTask` is redundant (and should be affecting performance) because you already call it from a thread. You basically are asking a thread to create a new thread.

Comment: Yes,Second AsyncTask(AddressAsync) you are calling from first AsyncTask(LocAsync).

Comment: also onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() in second asynctask are empty.

Comment: I did that on purpose because I was trying to reatin the loading screen or apply a new one. But unfortunately it did not allow me to apply any loading screen there.

Comment: Just call the code the relevant code method internally in the first `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Let me try on that.

Comment: i think you should call `dialog.hide()` from `onPostexecute()` of `AddressAsync` you can pass the dialog reference just as you are passing the Context in the constructor of `LocationDSR`